# install curl extension fail

Tags: php

I try to install php curl extension in my win xp environment but failed.
To follow the manual ,I have copied libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll into %systemroot%/system32 dir ,the ';' in front of 'extension=php_curl.dll' also has been opened 
but in the test function phpinfo(), there is still not any clues

but the other extensions like php_gd2.dll,php_pdo.dll can be opened or closed without any problems

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

use this function to try and load the file itself
http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php

then run extension_loaded() to check if it worked.

Then you can test if it is actually a path problem. Sometimes there are multiple extension directories. make sure you are using the right one.